# rbenv not setting the ruby version correctly

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I installed rbenv successfully and this appears correct:

```
piousboxs-MacBook-Pro:lms piousbox$ cat .rbenv-version
1.8.7-p374
piousboxs-MacBook-Pro:lms piousbox$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin12.2.1]
piousboxs-MacBook-Pro:lms piousbox$ which ruby
/Users/piousbox/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

But when I run `bundle`, it uses the system ruby somehow?

```
Installing tiny_tds (0.5.1)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes
checking for sybfront.h... no
-----
freetds is missing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install and select a version of Ruby to use; `rbenv` defaults to the system one, even if you've used `rbenv install` to add another.

To see which Ruby `rbenv` is going to use, just run `rbenv version`.

See [rbenv local](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-local) or [rbenv global](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-global) or [rbenv shell](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-shell) for details on how to set the version of Ruby in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Emil Sit, the problem is that somehow freetds tries to use the system ruby, even though rbenv is configured correctly. There is this --ruby flag being passed when building native extensions:

```
Installing tiny_tds (0.5.1)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --ruby=/Users/piousbox/.rbenv/shims/ruby
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes
checking for sybfront.h... yes
checking for sybdb.h... yes
checking for tdsdbopen() in -lsybdb... no
-----
freetds is missing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --enable-lookup
    --disable-lookup
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-freetds-dir
    --without-freetds-dir
    --with-freetds-include
    --without-freetds-include=${freetds-dir}/include
    --with-freetds-lib
    --without-freetds-lib=${freetds-dir}/lib
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib
    --with-sybdblib
    --without-sybdblib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/piousbox/.bundler/tmp/26769/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/piousbox/.bundler/tmp/26769/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/ext/tiny_tds/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing tiny_tds (0.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install tiny_tds -v '0.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've run `rbenv rehash` after installing bundler with `gem install bundler`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the system-provided bundler from /usr/local/bundle, as it is outdated and does not run very well. With my new ruby (via rbenv) and bundler (via new ruby) I was able to compile everything correctly.